# how to search for enable element in calender and click it?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to know the codes for clicking on active element(date) in calendar and also active radio buttons of a airline page.How can i do that? please help..

I have tired with a particular date, but after some time it is not able to click that element..with error--unable to locate element...

Here is code :-

```
public class Oneway 

{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException { 

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\elephant\\chromedriverw.exe");
{

//Launch crome n maximise window
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.vueling.com/es");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

//selecting dropdowm origin n destination

driver.findElement(By.name("AvailabilitySearchInputXmlSearchView$TextBoxMarketOrigin1")).sendKeys("Barcelona");

Actions a=new Actions(driver);
    a.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
    a.build().perform();
     Thread.sleep(2000); 

a.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    driver.findElement(By.name("AvailabilitySearchInputXmlSearchView$TextBoxMarketDestination1")).sendKeys("Madrid");


Actions a1=new Actions(driver);
for (int i=1; i<=1; i++)
a1.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);a.build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);

a.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);


// Date Picker

driver.findElement(By.id("divBuscadorCalendarTarget"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#datePickerContainer > div.ui-datepicker-group.ui-datepicker-group-first > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(4) > a")).click();
   Thread.sleep(5000);


   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#datePickerContainer > div.ui-datepicker-group.ui-datepicker-group-last > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > a")).click();


   driver.findElement(By.xpath("/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/FORM[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[8]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/A[1]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This is able to click the values of calendar.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

For Chrome driver

You need the exe to run chromedriver which is avialble at

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.21/
Just Extract it and give its path to following.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path where the exe is");
```

For e.g.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\pathto\\my\\chromedriver.exe");


WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("http://www.vueling.com/es#");
Thread.sleep(4000L);

WebElement  element  = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='marketDate1_lab']"));
element.click();
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
WebElement b = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='datePickerContainer']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]/a"));
a.moveToElement(b).build().perform();
b.click();

WebElement c =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='datePickerContainer']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]/a"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='datePickerContainer']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]/a")));
c.click();
```

Reply me for further Query. Happy Learning :-)

Comment: > Getting this error :- 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

 at vueling.Oneway.main(Oneway.java:60)

Comment: You using chromedriver? This is for firefox. Try it in firefox. I ran the code before sending it to you.

Comment: In my company, they only use chrome, for that reason i have tried it for chrome with setup.

Comment: See i have edited the answer for chrome. Hope this will help you. Reply to me for further query.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\elephant\\chromedriverw.exe");

Comment: chromedriver_win32.zip take this zip from the above link which i have shared.
Extract it . It will become  chromedriver.exe
And then give the path of this exe.. Hope you can relate to me.

Comment: Thank you @Kishan, Can you please tell me,, How to search for active element and click it..as i am in airline project..the flights page changes dynamically...the flight is available now after 1 hour it is disable..so, i need to find flight which are active in that table..what will be code for that..Thanks in advance

Comment: So you can you isenabled method of selenium.
Webelement a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).isEnabled();
So if it is enabled put your code in true and in false just print something that the element is not currently available.

Comment: With this code can i move to next element in the table, if the said element is false..Or can i search for table contains i e., searching within table value or property to click an active element? Thank you..

Comment: Yeah. You can move to next element . If element is Enabled perform the true part or print the false part and continue to next step.